# Repeat conditional formatting formula

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using Google Sheets and I have a pattern that repeats every 10 rows: A number in A1 and other stuff in A2:A10. Then the same again: A different number in A11 and other stuff in A12:A20. I want to apply conditional formatting to each block, based on the first number. For example, turn all A1:A10 cells green if A1 is greater than 5. The problem is I want to do it for the whole column and for all new blocks, without having to enter the formula each time a block is added. Is it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a helper column B with this formula:

```
=INDIRECT("A" & ROUNDUP(ROW(B1),-1)-9)
```

It will return the value of the first cell in each group, repeated down the column (rows 1:10 will show the value from row 1, etc). Then, apply the conditional formatting based on that column.

Comment: Actually, using the formula Emma suggested, you can create a conditional format with a custom formula. Just create the conditional format from A1:A and write in the custom formula field =INDIRECT("A" & ROUNDUP(ROW(B1),-1)-9)>5

Comment: Thanks, Eliana! That's much cleaner :)

Comment: Haha I had to test it out first to make sure it would work :)